# Retrieving values from multi level array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, decode

Hi would love some help on how to perform this. Cause so far what I'm doing now is failing.
this is the sample output of json turned to array.

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => lit-PR-00-Preparing-Precise-Polymer-Solutions.html
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 90Plus
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Particle Size Analyzer
                    )

            )

    )
```

So far this is what I got so far and It's still not outputting the value I need. Would appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong thanks.

```
$decode = json_decode($row['elements'], true);

                echo '<pre>';
                //print_r($decode);
                print_r(array_values($decode));
                echo '</pre>';

                echo ($value['0'][1][value]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$decode = json_decode($row['elements'], true);

// iterate through array
foreach($decode as $array_row) {
  echo $array_row[0]['value'];
}

// display specific row #2
echo $decode[2][0]['value'];
```

- [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)